# Create an Index of Cumulative Returns from Monthly Stock Returns

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, finance, performanceanalytics

I'm still quite the rookie data wrangle-R and am struggling to find a solution to this.

Here's what my data frame with monthly percentage changes looks like:

```
Month    Security1 Security2 ... SecurityN
1970-01   -2.30%     1.02%         0.64%
1970-02    1.87%    -0.01%         9.50%
1970-03    3.38%     2.33%         5.56%
```

I am trying to get a data frame outputted with each security's monthly return (>1500 of them) indexed to show cumulative return, like so:

```
Month    Security1 Security2 ... SecurityN
1970-01     100       100           100
1970-02    101.87    99.99         109.50
1970-03    105.32    102.32        115.59
```

I have tried using:

```
cum.ret <- apply(dataframe, 2, function(x) Return.cumulative(x, geometric = TRUE))
```

But this only returns how much each stock has made since inception: e.g. Security1 returned 121%, Security2 returned 233%, etc.

Asides from loading the data, I have no other code in the notebook.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
mydf[-1] <- lapply(mydf[-1], function(x) as.numeric(sub('%','',x)))
mydf[1,-1] <- 100
mydf[-1] <- lapply(mydf[-1], cumsum)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > mydf
>     Month Security1 Security2 SecurityN
> 1 1970-01    100.00    100.00    100.00
> 2 1970-02    101.87     99.99    109.50
> 3 1970-03    105.25    102.32    115.06
> ```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- read.table(text="Month    Security1 Security2  SecurityN
1970-01   -2.30%     1.02%         0.64%
1970-02    1.87%    -0.01%         9.50%
1970-03    3.38%     2.33%         5.56%", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: If my data had different start dates, how could I apply the cumsum function, where it bases the index to each securities' respective inception date?  e.g. one security starts in Feb-1970, with the base of 100 being in Jan-1970, and another security starts in Jun-1980, with the base being May-1980, and so on?  Thanks in advance!